# Image disappears after first frame, iOS, OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl-es, ios4

I wrote a program which should render a cone to the screen. The problem is that in the first frame I can see the cone displaying correctly on my iOS simulate screen; after that, the cone disappears. When I set a break point, all the data seems to be OK to me.

I am using OpenGL ES 1.0.

Comment: Most likely you are setting some state to wrong value. Check your enable/disable calls for lighthing, blending, depth test, and other state. Also veryify buffer bindings if you use client arrays or VBO's.

Comment: An excerpt of your code would help us a lot :) We don't have yet a crystal ball :)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you should show us some code... But for all it's worth, I had the same problem and in my case the error was that I was calling the`glEnableClientState(...)`at the initialisation stage while the`glDisableClientState(...)`at every frame (every`Render()` call).